# How to create a serializer and a view to create a sub-category in django and djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created three classes
1. Programme  - parent - example Bachelor of Arts(BA)
2. Semester   - child  - first semester- child of programme
3. Course     - grand child - Chemistry-1, child of semester

Detail: 
1) There will be many semester under the programme, link using foreign key
2) There will be many courses under semester.

How to implement this behavior in djangorestframework. 
1) Create a course under a semester
2) to list all the courses under a programme and semester

```
class Programme(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     def __str__(self):
          return self.name


class Semester(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     numeric = models.IntegerField()
     programme = models.ForeignKey(Programme, 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester,
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='courses')
    internal = models.IntegerField()
    external = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far, perhaps the DRF views, serializer classes you've defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use method field in serializer to and add that as a exptra field in class meta to get the full list and subcategory:

## serializer.py

```
class courseserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = course
      fields = '__all__'

class semesterserilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   course=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   class Meta:
      model = course
      fields = ['name','course']
   def get_course(self,obj):
       queryset=course.objects.filter(id=obj.id)
       return courseserializer(queryset,many=True).data
```

same you will have to do with programme to get both the serilaizer inside the programme and in view passs the queryset in the parent serilizer that will fetch the relevent data as we directed in serilizer.